# How to check if a string contains an exact substring in Php

Tags: php, strpos

I am trying to check if a number say `1` is present in a string say `11,12,13` To do this I am using `strpos`:

```
<?
$s = "2,3,11,12,13";
$ss = "1";
if(strpos($s, $ss)) echo "success";
else echo "fail";
?>
```

Here I am expecting the code to give `fail` as output but it gives `success`.
Is there any function I can use to exactly match the number in a string. I want the number `1` in the string, not the numbers containing `1` like `11,123,100` etc.

**Edit 1:** It works fine for @Twinfriends answer but the problem is doing it with multiple numbers.

```
<?
    $s = "2,3,11,12,13";
    $ss = "1,2";
    if(strpos($s, $ss)) echo "success";
    else echo "fail";
    ?>
```

This code gives output `fail` but it should give true.

**Edit 2:** Check answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48297002/8490014

The problem has been solved but because of for each loop the output is getting repeated as many times as there are values in the array. How can we get the output repeating the output?

Comment: Is `"1,2,3,4,5"` would return success with `1`?

Comment: little note: `strpos` may return int(0) so better use `===` to compare   `if(strpos($s, $ss) !== false)`

Comment: To your edit 2: What have you tried so far? Its really easy solving this problem that you only get the output once, I'm ready to help you, but I won't give you the solution without you showing any effort to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been solved by adding a `foreach` loop:

```
<?
$s = "2,3,11,12,13";
$ss = "1,2,3,5";

$catid = explode(",", $s);
$ocat = explode(",",$ss);

    foreach($ocat as $abc) {
if(in_array($abc, $catid)) {
 echo "success";
}
else {
echo "fail";
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
<?php

$s = "2,3,11,12,13";
$ss = "1";

$toTest = explode(",", $s);

if(in_array("$ss", $toTest)) {
    echo "success";
}
else {
    echo "fail";
}

?>
```

If you've any question considering this code, feel free to ask. (Code tested, works well)

Comment: @EvilTech What will be the maximum count of numbers in `$ss` ? 2, or even more?

Comment: It could be more but always less than or equal to `$s`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$s = "2,3,11,12,13";
$ss = "1";

$haystack = explode(",",$s);
$matches  = preg_grep ("/$ss/", $haystack);

echo !empty($matches) ? "success" : "fail";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check by `appending comma` after the `variable` to check occurrence at `start`, `appending comma` before the `variable` to check occurrence at `last` or `appending comma` before and after the `variable` to check occurrence at `middle`.

```
if((substr($s, 0, (strlen($ss)+1)) === $ss.',')||(substr($s, (strlen($s)-strlen($ss)-1), strlen($s)) === ','.$ss)||(strpos($s, ','.$ss.','))){
        echo "success";
}
else{
        echo "fail";
}
```